# Multiply a column deppending on the value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with a "Weather" column, and other column that has the "eta".

What I want to do is basically multiply the eta time by a random number, and the range of that number depends on the climate.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
If(Climate == 'Sunny') then 'eta' = 'eta' * Random(0.8*1.0)
else if (Climate == 'Rainny') then 'eta' = 'eta' * Random(1.0*1.2)

else if (Climate == 'Cloudy') then 'eta' = 'eta' * Random(0.9*1.1)
```

I dont know how to achieve this using a Pandas DataFrame, my best aproximation was this but didnt work.

```
df.loc[df['Climate'] == 'Rain', 'eta' * random.uniform(1.0, 1.2)]
```

I expected it to multiply the eta column by a rand value between 1.0-1.2 if the value of the 'eta' column was 'Rain'

Comment: It would be great to provide a minimal reproducible example with your own data!

Comment: I'll do it on future posts! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use:

```
min_max = {'Sunny': (0.8, 1), 'Rainy': (1, 1.2)}

df['eta'] = (df.groupby('Climate')['eta']
               .apply(lambda x: x*np.random.uniform(*min_max[x.name], size=len(x)))
             )
```

Example (as new column for clarity):

```
  Climate       eta   new_eta
0   Sunny  3.258367  3.026513
1   Sunny  5.615873  4.962923
2   Sunny  4.046182  3.761648
3   Sunny  0.367640  0.296795
4   Sunny  2.875452  2.677827
5   Rainy  3.576453  3.856957
6   Rainy  5.674834  5.895780
7   Rainy  7.876974  8.576879
8   Rainy  8.098803  9.473710
9   Rainy  0.750729  0.841462
```

For a vectorial approach, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
min_max = {'Sunny': (0.8, 1), 'Rainy': (1, 1.2)}

low, up = (pd.DataFrame(min_max, index=['min', 'max'])
             .reindex(columns=df['Climate']).to_numpy()
           )

a = np.random.random(size=len(df))

df['eta'] *= a*(up-low)+low
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Someone posted another solution which also worked and deleted it afterwards... Not sure why:  df.loc[df['Climate'] == 'Rain', 'eta'] *= np.random.uniform(1.0, 1.2)

Comment: @Alberto glad it worked! the `loc` approach is similar to my `groupby` approach, but manual. This is a decent option if you only have a handful of conditions and want to type them manually ;)

Comment: Actually the other solution was multiplying all rows of the same group by a unique factor. My solution multiplies all rows independently by a different factor for each one but within the same boundaries. If you want a unique factor use my first solution removing the `size` parameter ;)

Comment: Oh, so the solution that the other user sent multiplies all the rows with the same climate by the same number? I want each row of the same climate to be multiplied by a different random number between the range of that climate. So the only real solution is yours!

Comment: In this case, yes ;)

Comment: I've been working on this and I have a question, what's the purpouse of "*" before min_max[x.name]? I've been using python for a week and never seen that notation

Comment: This is called parameter expansion. `min_max[x.name]` is an iterable of 2 items, `uniform(*min_max[x.name])` expands the 2 values as parameters of `uniform`. In short: `f(*[a, b])` is equivalent to `f(a, b)`.