# Multiply column by a random value between a range depending on the month of the date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with a "Date" column, and other column that has the "eta".

What I want to do is basically multiply the eta time by a random number, and the range of that number depends on the month.

I almost got the solution but the issue is that it multiplies all the rows that has one of those months by the same number (It gets just one random number which applies to all columns) what I want to do is to recalculate that random number for each row that has the chosen months.

I would post the dataframe visualization as a table but I dont know how to do it and pictures are not allowed.

My code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
df.loc[df['Date'].dt.month.isin((1,2,3)), 'eta'] *= random.uniform(1,2)
```

Comment: What is problem with previous solution - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766034/multiply-a-column-deppending-on-the-value-of-other-column/75766071#75766071) ?

Comment: You likely want `m = df['Date'].dt.month.isin((1,2,3)) ; df.loc[m, 'eta'] *= np.random.uniform(1, 2, m.sum())`

Comment: @jezrael there is no problem with that solution, but now I'm working with another column (Date) and I dont know how to apply the previous solution to this case, because previously I wanted to check if the value of a column was that string and now the issue is that it has to be between some months

Comment: @mozway as always, that's the correct answer! Thanks for helping me! I hope I get to know as much about programming as you know one day!

Comment: @Alberto OK, then this is not the same logic as your previous question. I added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mask for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) with a `size` equal to the number of `True` of the mask (counted using [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)):

```
m = df['Date'].dt.month.isin((1,2,3))
df.loc[m, 'eta'] *= np.random.uniform(1, 2, m.sum())
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31', freq='MS'),
                   'eta': range(1, 13)})

m = df['Date'].dt.month.isin((1,2,3))
df.loc[m, 'eta'] *= np.random.uniform(1, 2, m.sum())
```

Output:

```
         Date        eta
0  2023-01-01   1.704245  # values multiplied
1  2023-02-01   2.051441  # each by a different
2  2023-03-01   5.712714  # random factor
3  2023-04-01   4.000000
4  2023-05-01   5.000000
5  2023-06-01   6.000000
6  2023-07-01   7.000000
7  2023-08-01   8.000000
8  2023-09-01   9.000000
9  2023-10-01  10.000000
10 2023-11-01  11.000000
11 2023-12-01  12.000000
```